# What does "Anonymous modules have no name to be referenced by" really mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.9

I'm upgrading my Rails app to work with Ruby 1.9 and I keep encountering errors like this:

```
Anonymous modules have no name to be referenced by
/home/foo/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:585:in `to_constant_name'
/home/foo/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:391:in `qualified_name_for'
/home/foo/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:104:in `rescue in const_missing'
/home/foo/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:94:in `const_missing'
/home/foo/app/config/environment.rb:66:in `block in <top (required)>'
etc.
```

Google finds all kinds of hits for this, but each of them pertains to a specific fix for one specific gem or app. None of them explain what the message really means.

- What is an "anonymous module"?
- Where is this error message coming from? (The Ruby interpreter itself?)
- What is different about Ruby 1.9 that causes this? (Rails 2.3.8 with Ruby 1.8.7 does not encounter this.)
- What is the general/proper way to fix this error?

Line 66 of environment.rb is the configuration for [super_exception_notifier](http://github.com/pboling/exception_notification) (old version, 2.0.8):

```
ExceptionNotifier.configure_exception_notifier do |config|
  config[:sender_address] = %("Foo" <foo@foo.com>)
  config[:exception_recipients] = %w(foo@foo.com)
  config[:skip_local_notification] = false
end
```

From what I can tell, ExceptionNotifier is undefined, and ActiveSupport is trying to magically load it, but fails and then fails again trying to print a nice error message.

Comment: check for name collisions in method/module names in your app with rails. obscure errors often happen when your code stuff collides with AR.

Answer (score 6):

An anonymous module is a module that is declared like so:

```
Fred = Module.new do
  def meth1
    "hello"
  end
  def meth2
    "bye"
  end
end
```

instead of by using the regular `Module mod_name <block>` syntax.  Since they have no module name, you can't retrieve the module name.  `to_constant_name` is attempting to call `desc.name.blank?` where `desc` is an anonymous module (with no `name`).

This error is coming from the ActiveSupport module, which may indicate a bug in the active_support gem or may indicate that some other piece of code is using ActiveSupport incorrectly.  The error message alone doesn't give enough information to identify the culprit (to me at least, someone with more rails experience might be able to provide more insight).

Without knowing the offending code it's also hard to say exactly why this error is popping up with 1.9, or what needs to be done to fix it.  Considering that there are a lot of un- and under-maintained gems out there that have not been updated for 1.9 yet, I would suspect that ActiveSupport is not the source of the problem.  Upgrade all of your gems that have 1.9-compatible versions, and then try disabling your other gems one at a time (if you can) and see if you still get the error.

If you provide a list of the other gems that you are using, someone else who may have encountered the error before may be able to provide some details.

Answer (score 3):

This may happen if you try to exploit ActiveRecord's internal class and module contexts in the wrong way. I had this error yesterday while working on a gem which extends deep inner workings of ActiveRecord. I finally managed to get around this problem by redesigning my code which exploits the inner contexts. It would be interesting to see the surrounding lines of `environment.rb:66` for further analysis.

Answer (score 1):

This may happen when the class name doesn't match the filename, in 
my case it was a file named application.rb contaning the ApplicationController
class. Renaming the file to application_controller.rb solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When I got this error, it was due to a misspelling while defining a class. If you are getting this error, it may be worth examining your module and class definitions for typos.

Comment: Kinda late to the party, I know, but the other answers (while informative) do not really offer advice concerning specific items to start checking.